# Summation and combination

Tags: combinatorics

Show that

$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}\right)^2=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{2n \choose k}$

I am having trouble showing it using mathematical induction.

Comment: You don't need induction for this.$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}=2^n$$ See how that basically makes the equation trivial?

Comment: Alternatively, a combinatorial proof is generally quite nice and elegant.  There are $n$ men and $n$ women in a committee.  We ask how many subcommittees we can form.  On the left-hand-side we count the number of subcommittees by taking a subset of the men and a subset of the women individually and combining them.  On the right we simply take a subset of the $2n$ people as a whole regardless of gender.  Ranging over all possible sizes, we get the aforementioned identity.